# Как сделать селекты в два столбца, но без flex-wrap?

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы селекты не врапались при уменьшении экрана, а сжимались, как это возможно сделать? Врап установил для того, чтобы селекты были в два столбца(скрин)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.rating-filter
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.column:first-child select
{
    width: 391px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--gray, #777C86);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20);
}
.column:nth-child(2) select
{
    width: 859px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid var(--gray, #777C86);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20);
}
.column:nth-child(3) select
{
    width: 389px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid var(--gray, #777C86);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20);
}
.column:nth-child(4) p
{
    color: var(--2-black, #2C2A3B);
    font-family: Manrope, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: normal;
}
.column:nth-child(5) input
{
    margin-left: 23px;
    width: 796px;
    height: 66px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--gray, #777C86);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20);
}
.column:nth-child(6) select
{
    width: 695px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    border: 1px solid var(--gray, #777C86);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20);
}
```

```html
      <div class="rating-filter">
        <div class="column">
          <select class="select">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <select>
            <option value="7">Option 7</option>
            <option value="8">Option 8</option>
            <option value="9">Option 9</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <select>
            <option value="7">Option 7</option>
            <option value="8">Option 8</option>
            <option value="9">Option 9</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <p>Фильтровать:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <input type="text" placeholder="текст">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <select>
            <option value="7">Option 7</option>
            <option value="8">Option 8</option>
            <option value="9">Option 9</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: А вы зачем вообще `flex-wrap` ставили? Знаете что оно делает?

Comment: @eccs0103 Переносит на новую строку, попытался другими способами, через float: left - не получилось, также переносит, не подскажите через что можно тогда в два столбца вывести, чтобы они не переносили, а сужались?

Comment: Так вот если вы не хотите перенести, уберите `flex-wrap`. `display: flex;` достаточно чтобы все дочерние элементы встали в ряд. Чтобы прям закрепить это можете `flex-direction: column;` добавить.

Comment: А если именно 2 элемента надо в ряд, это лучше с `display: grid;` делать. С `flex` слишком придется заморачиватся

Comment: @eccs0103 Если просто с display: flex, то он будет идти в ряд, а не столбцами вниз. Сейчас попробую через грид

Comment: Для вертикального строя надо `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: @eccs0103 Он просто выстраивается вертикально, а не в два ряда. С гридом тоже чет не пойму(

Comment: `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);`

Comment: @eccs0103 Ошибся, нужно в три ряда, т.е. display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);, но тогда он ставит их в одной ширине получается, как можно уменьшить ширину у блока с текстом? Как на скрине в общем

Comment: `grid-template-columns: ширина_столбца_1 ширина_столбца_2 ширина_столбца_3;`

Answer (score 0):

Вместо фиксированой ширины прописать динамическую.

```
.column:first-child select
{
    width: Значение;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    border: 1px solid var(--gray, #777C86);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.20);
}
```

a) Если отталкиваешься от ширины экрана используй vw или dvw
б) Если от родителя то %.
в) Если надо сохранять ширину на какой то части то использукй `calc`

К примеру родитель имеет ширину 1000px
надо оставить левому блоку ширину в 100px а 2 и 3 равные значяение то.
Стиль 1 блока

```
width:100px
```

2 и 3

```
width:calc(50% - 50px)
```

Калк((100%\ на количенство динамических блоков) = 50% - (ширина статического блока\ деленная на количенство динамических блоков) = 50%

так же используй min-width и max-width

Comment: Варпы и прочее отвечает за положения, а тебе (судя по вопросу) нужно их сжать, значить лезь в ширину

Answer (score 0):

Что то у Вас со стилями сложно было так что лишнее я убрал. Надеюсь суть группировки понятна.

```css
p{
  margin: 0;
}

.rating-filter
{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 5px;
}

.rating-filter .group {
    display: flex;    
    flex: 1;
    gap: 5px;
}

.rating-filter .group select {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-filter">
      <div class="group">
        <select class="select">
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option value="7">Option 7</option>
          <option value="8">Option 8</option>
          <option value="9">Option 9</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option value="7">Option 7</option>
          <option value="8">Option 8</option>
          <option value="9">Option 9</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <p>Фильтровать:</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="текст" />
        <select>
          <option value="7">Option 7</option>
          <option value="8">Option 8</option>
          <option value="9">Option 9</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```